# glGenBuffers Segmentation Fault when using SDL,GLEW on Debian

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, sdl

I am working on an engine project, using SDL + OpenGL. It worked under windows in the same computer(so same graphic hardware) without problem but after installing Debian which I have no any familiarity, when I tried to compile the project(with small changes related to including files("/" - "\" issue)) with gcc under Debian/Linux it said something like " GLSL 3.30 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.00 ES, 1.10, 1.20". I encounted the case it just runs some old version funcions like glClear when version setting is not ok where just a cyan window appeared, before, so thought I should install drivers first.Installed fglrx-driver from package manager(`apt-get install fglrx-driver`), configured it by the command `aticonfig --initial` as a message popped on terminal suggested during somewhere of the installation.After the configuration, the application I tried to recompile gave an error like "Segmentation Fault" and I recognised that functions like glGenBuffer,glBindBuffer is causing the error, some of the functions of new versions after leaving the ones of 'fixed pipeline system' deprecated alone.Now, is the problem still related to version/context binding, if so, what should I do to be able to correctly call OpenGL 3.3+ functions in any c++ application on Debian.(The parameters of compilation are `` g++ -o program source.cpp `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -lGLEW -lGL ``), if not, what is the problem and what do you suggest to fix this?

**Extra Information :**

To check the version of fglrx, `ls /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/ outputs` :

`12-6+point  kernel-3.2.0-4-amd64-x86_64`
.

fglrx outputs :
`display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD TURKS
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 8.0.5)`

although [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) it shows like this: 

`display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 4300/4500 Series

OpenGL version string: 3.3.11399 Compatibility Profile Context`

(just look at second item in the site)

If the problem is about version specifying what is wrong with these:

    `SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION,4);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION,3);`

(I tried also 1-4, 2-3, 1-3 as minor-major)

Notice, I am not using Ubuntu originated from Debian 7(wheezy), the OS is Debian, the graphics card is :

`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Thames XT/GL [Radeon HD 7600M Series]`

(Output of `lspci | grep VGA`)

At the moment, I know that Mesa is open-source implemention of OpenGL specification by an old research yesterday. So if the problem is a configuration related to how the abstract specification of OpenGL will comminicate with hardware, how can I switch from mesa to fglrx in order to implement OpenGL 3.3 and above? Lastly, which drive do you suggest to use, free or non-free one?

Comment: Which version of Debian is it, and which package of fglrx are you installing?

Comment: Debian 7 (wheezy), 12-6+point  kernel-3.2.0-4-amd64-x86_64

Comment: The version of fglrx from the stable packages is pretty old. You may want to upgrade your packages to newer versions or manually install a version of fglrx from the AMD website.

Comment: By the way, you have just stepped into the strange world of linux graphics drivers. You will encounter strange crashes, strange bugs, and just general frustration (especially with FGLRX). Welcome to The Twilight Zone!

Comment: What does glxinfo report?

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your comforting comment 'Welcome to The Twilight Zone' :P
the glxinfo outputs :
can't output because the maximum size of string is not enough for this comment area.I had to remove the too long output part.

Comment: You could try posting it to pastebin.com and posting the link to it here.

Comment: I uploaded what it outputs in txt format;
[the link](http://s3.dosya.tc/server26/pOvSbM/output.txt.html)

Comment: You don't have direct rendering, according to glxinfo. Which fglrx packages do you have installed, specifically?

Comment: Yes, I did exactly what you said.(Uploded another place).Unfortunately, pastebin.com was prohibited here so I have had to use something else.

Comment: I don't know. I may not have done correctly or completely whatever I should do. What I did was just to install it with `apt-get install fglrx-driver` . If this won't work alone, what is next?

Comment: It looks like you're using mesa libGL with the fglrx driver. Try installing libgl1-fglrx-glx and fglrx-modules-dkms with apt-get if you haven't already.

Comment: It says that the both are already newest version.

Comment: Is fglrx-atieventsd installed? Also, what is the output of 'update-alternatives --display glx'?

Comment: It says "fglrx-atieventsd is already the newest version
         fglrx-atieventsd set to manually installed." and what you said outputs:
`glx - auto mode
  link currently points to /usr/lib/fglrx
/usr/lib/fglrx - priority 99
  slave glx--fglrx_drv.so: /usr/lib/fglrx/fglrx_drv.so
  slave glx--libGL.so.1-x86_64-linux-gnu: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/fglrx/libGL.so.1
  slave glx--linux-libglx.so: /usr/lib/fglrx/fglrx-libglx.so
/usr/lib/mesa-diverted - priority 5
  slave glx--libGL.so.1-x86_64-linux-gnu: /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
Current 'best' version is '/usr/lib/fglrx'.
`

Comment: What is the output of uname?

Comment: the output :             Linux

Comment: Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Do you have linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64 installed?

Comment: It says "linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64 is already the newest version.
         linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64 set to manually installed."

Comment: Try "LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo"

Comment: http://www.dosya.tc/server33/cWSvEd/output.txt.html

Comment: LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo | grep rendering

Comment: direct rendering: No (If you want to find out why, try setting LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose)

Comment: It returned to the begining again. So what? What is wrong? Maybe, it was my mistake to directly pass the command you send to terminal?
`LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo`

Comment: Are you sure that's correct? That should be bringing up more information... Try purging the fglrx packages and reinstalling them, and post the install logs if that doesn't work.

Comment: Must I uninstall all packages one by one or is there a more general command you can suggest like `apt-get purge fglrx-driver` ?

Comment: The reason why I care that much is because I mistakenly deleted all packages serviceable before by purge command.

Comment: I would just apt-get purge each one (you can issue more than one at once to apt-get) individually to make sure. First, though, type glxgears and see if that runs at all.

Comment: Yes, it runs so sould I still purge all fglrx related stuff, if they have to be removed, can you list which ones sould I delete before the reinstallation?

Comment: Try purging anything that starts with fglrx, and also libgl1-fglrx-glx. Then reinstall them all at once.

Comment: First, I couldn't delete all startinng with fglrx but could purge libgl-fglrx-glx by writing  `sudo apt-get purge fglrx-driver libgl1-fglrx-glx` and mistakenly install them.So I know that libgl1-fglrx-glx has been already purged and installed.Later I remembered that I can purge all starting with fglrx by fglrx* so did that way.Now, is it ok? Here is what I did : [output](http://s3.dosya.tc/server26/4XwBgP/output.txt.html)

Comment: Now, I completely drove mad. After rebooting, gnome 3 has gone, probably related to fglrx and ati configurations.The appearance of GUI changed, I can't tune the brightness/contrast of screen anymore.As you said, I am struggling in the exotic world of linux graphics drivers.Thanks for all your attempts to help by the way.

Comment: Gnome 3 is gone? Did it get uninstalled? What is being used now?

Comment: Ok, I just recognised it didn't go. `gnome-shell --version` has outputed `GNOME Shell 3.4.2
`.It has came again in a different form after changing xlog.conf with content of xorg.conf.original-1 stating that there were no such a file as xlog.conf file before the addition, which was probably result of aticonfig --initial attempt.

Comment: After I managed to enter again with gui, A message stating that gnome 3 couldn't start because of some graphic problems so that it needed to start in secure mode, popped up.Before that, I deleted the fglrx device part of xlog.conf file in /etc/X11, which was probably wrong way of disabling fglrx before purging it.

Comment: This may be the cause of normal gui that isn't avaliable to start properly.Just usual appearance of the gui has changed.Everything works except graphic card-related applications such as games.The simple sdl_test application can no longer show a window with cyan background by glClearColor-glClear.Probably, something related to fgrx/ATI configuration is wrong.At the moment, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Oh, that was the gnome 3 graphics fallback mode. At this point, I would recommend trying to install the latest driver from AMD through their install script rather than through debians package system: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86#amd-catalyst-packages    Alternatively, if you switch from debian stable to testing, both the fglrx and open source drivers in testings repositories are much more recent and will work better with your card. I don't know if switching from stable is an option for you, though.

Comment: I downloaded and installed the proprietary one but it still doesn't work.Is it due to unenabled drives.What should I do at that point?

Comment: Meanwhile, aticonfig --initial outputs : ``aticonfig: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
``

Comment: Is it ok to purge libGL and reinstall? Or what's your suggestion? It is most probably an ultra simple issue but I can't overcome because I am very new to linux world.

Comment: Okay, I've run into this exact issue before. I'm trying to figure out how I fixed it before.

Comment: I am waiting for getting any feedback related to the topic from you.

Comment: What are the contents of /usr/lib/mesa-diverted?

Comment: Could not open : 
``
root@debian:~# gedit /usr/lib/mesa-diverted

(gedit:5884): EggSMClient-WARNING **: Failed to connect to the session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported


** (gedit:5884): WARNING **: Could not connect to session bus
``

Comment: It's a folder, not a file. Since you're on a x86-64 platform, there should be an i386 folder and an x86-64 folder. They both should contain some symlinks and libGL.so files. Do they?

Comment: Yes, they do : `root@debian:~# ls /usr/lib/mesa-diverted
i386-linux-gnu libGL.so-master  x86_64-linux-gnu
`

Comment: What are the contents of each folder?

Comment: `root@debian:/usr/lib/mesa-diverted# ls i386-linux-gnu libGL.so-master  x86_64-linux-gnu
i386-linux-gnu:

libGL.so-master:
i386-linux-gnu libGL.so-master  x86_64-linux-gnu

x86_64-linux-gnu:
libGL.so  libGL.so.1  libGL.so.1.2
`

Comment: /usr/lib/mesa-diverted/i386-linux-gnu is empty?

Comment: What are the contents of /usr/lib/fglrx?

Comment: It says that there is no such a directory.

Comment: Can I give up proprietary one and give a chance to open-source test library to make the process easier at this point?

Comment: X doesn't seem to find fglrx according to last log file(var/log/Xorg.log.1) if the problem is not about installation of fglrx driver.
here is the copied contents of the file(uploaded with the same file-name) : [contents_of_the_log_file](http://s3.dosya.tc/server27/X5mZoY/output.txt.html)

Comment: I have no idea why fglrx is failing to install this badly every time. I would recommend the open source driver now, but only with xserver-xorg-core at version 1.16 or higher. Versions before this will not have glamor built in, which is required for 3D acceleration on Southern Island cards (ie HD7000 series). The problem with this is, again, the newer packages are found in the testing repository, not the stable, so you would either need to try and install testing packages on stable, or upgrade to testing. I've recently switched to the open source, and for me it works better than fglrx.

Comment: I read somewhere about a few hours ago(I don't remember where), a text saying that after adding a source adress to source.list and updating with apt-get will enable installation from testing part by apt-get -t wheezy-backports "package-name". Can you give me a short list of what packages to install from testing section in order for ensuring that all graphic-related stuff will work.

Comment: There aren't any packages for that for wheezy-backports. If you look here: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/xserver-xorg-core you should be able to look at all dependencies of the package and note the version numbers. Anything that is a lower version in stable must be upgraded to the the testing version. I'm not even sure if you could install all these testing packages without just upgrading to testing. These packages were just released last month, as was xserver 1.16, so they are very recent.